`AVPlayerInterstitialEventController` doesn't work when the `primaryItem` is not a HLS stream
AVPlayerInterstitialEventController doesn't work when the primaryItem is not a HLS stream, despite the events being set manually.
Is there any workarounds for this? I want to use interstitials for non-HLS content (like podcast mp3 files).
Full example of the problem:
import UIKit
import AVKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let player = AVPlayer()
    private lazy var interstitialEventController = AVPlayerInterstitialEventController(primaryPlayer: player)
    private lazy var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addChild(playerViewController)
        view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        playerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 414, height: 232)
        playerViewController.player = player

        let primaryItem = AVPlayerItem(
            // mp4: doesn't work, interstitials are not triggered
            // url: URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")!

            // m3u8: works, interstitials are triggered
            url: URL(string: "https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8")!
        )

        let adItem = AVPlayerItem(
            url: URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4")!
        )

        interstitialEventController.events = [
            AVPlayerInterstitialEvent(
                primaryItem: primaryItem,
                identifier: "midroll",
                time: CMTime(seconds: 5, preferredTimescale: 1),
                templateItems: [
                    adItem
                ],
                restrictions: [
                    .constrainsSeekingForwardInPrimaryContent,
                    .requiresPlaybackAtPreferredRateForAdvancement
                ],
                resumptionOffset: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1)
            )
        ]

        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: primaryItem)
        player.play()
    }
}


For when someone comes quoting xkcd 979 years in the future: No, we never found a workaround (and stopped looking)
